# Java Jsoup как правильно сделать парсинг страницы

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Я решил сделать парсер страницы жалоб на игровом проекте. Допустим вот эта страница: https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov-majestic-roleplay.37/

Я всё делаю, создаю, пишу код, чтобы программа находила каждую жалобу, нашел уникальный атрибут(data-tp-primary="on"). Далее перебираю каждый элемент и вывожу атрибут href, но по итогу он изначально не нашел ни единого элемента. Прикладываю код класса AppParser:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AppParser {
    private Document doc;



    public static void appParse(int numberServer) throws IOException {
        Document doc = null;
        switch (numberServer) {
            case 1:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov-majestic-roleplay.37/").get();

                break;
            case 2:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.169/").get();

                break;
            case 3:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.247/").get();
                break;
            case 4:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.318/").get();
                break;
            case 5:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.474/").get();
                break;
            case 6:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.540/").get();
                break;
            case 7:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.652/").get();
                break;
            case 8:
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.majestic-rp.ru/forums/zhaloby-na-igrokov.762/").get();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Неверный сервер!");

        }

        Elements postTitleElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-tp-primary", "on");
        if (postTitleElements.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("empty");
        }
         postTitleElements.forEach(postTitleElement -> System.out.println(postTitleElement.attr("href")));



    }
}
```

Запускаю программу из метода main: AppParser.appParse(1). то есть проверяю только 1 сервер(первую ссылку). И далее уже сам сделал проверку через if если элементы пустые, и оно выводит в консоль empty.